# EF4 - ChangeObjectState is no longer accessible in RC

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

After migrated EF4 CTP5 to RC1, I notice the ObjectContext is no longer accessible through DbContext. It means I can't access ChangeObjectState method.

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
    {
    }

    public DataContext(DbCompiledModel dbModel)
        : base(dbModel)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }

    public void ChangeObjectState<T>(T entity, EntityState entityState)
    {
        // this is no longer working.. where is ObjectContext? 
        ObjectContext.ChangeObjectState(entity, entityState);
    }
}
```

Has anyone have any idea how access that method in RC1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to access `ObjectContext` to change object state. Use this:

```
this.Entry<T>(entity).State = entityState;
```